# Спрайтам в Pygame присваивается одно и тоже значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

При запуске цикла в методе createChunks класса GenerateChunks должно изменяться 2 число списка position и этот список передается как аргумент в класс Chunk.

```
import pygame

class Chunk(pygame.sprite.Sprite): 
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.chunkPos = pos

    def update(self):
        print(self.__dict__)

class GenerateChunks:
    def createChunks(self):
        ChunkGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
        position = [0,0]

        for i in range(10):
            position[1] += 1
            ChunkGroup.add(Chunk(position))

        return ChunkGroup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    group = GenerateChunks().createChunks()
    group.update()
```

После окончания работы цикла получается группа Pygame из 10 спрайтов, у которых одинаковое значение chunkPos.

```
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': [0, 10]}
```

Но если position будет не списком, а int, то на выходе получается группа уже с разными значениями chunkPos

```
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 1}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 2}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 3}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 4}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 5}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 6}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 7}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 8}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 9}
{'_Sprite__g': {<Group(10 sprites)>: 0}, 'chunkPos': 10}
```

Из за чего же может быть такая разница?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое поведения объясняется тем, что вы в строке `Chunk(position)` передаете не само значение переменной, а ссылку на исходное значение. Соответственно, когда вы меняете переменной `position`, меняются и атрибуты `self.chunkPos` во всех чанках. Можете поменять ваш код на такой, чтобы все работало корректно

```py
import pygame

class Chunk(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.chunkPos = pos

    def update(self):
        print(self.__dict__)

class GenerateChunks:
    def createChunks(self):
        ChunkGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for i in range(10):
            ChunkGroup.add(Chunk([0, i+1]))

        return ChunkGroup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    group = GenerateChunks().createChunks()
    group.update()
```

[Здесь](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/python-lists/lessons/references-and-mutation/theory_unit) можно почитать об этом